# When to use who/that/which or an infinitive?

Tags: word-usage, infinitives

Consider the following sets:

> It was the first movie to make me cry.
>
> He was the first man to scale Mount Everest.

> It was the first movie that made me cry.
>
> He was the first man who scaled Mount Everest.

Are both sets grammatically correct? The latter sounds better to my ears, but I don't understand the differences between them.

Comment: Both of them are same in meaning.

Comment: David, @Mistu4u is correct; the two sentences have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using "Which" or "That :**

There are two types of elements : Restrictive and Non Restrictive.

The word "that" is restrictive while "which" is non restrictive. Please refer this link for complete details : http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar-rules-and-tips/when-to-use-which-or-that.html

**Using an infinitive :**

An infinitive is used to denote a specific purpose , as a subject , after adjective and more.

This link can explain the uses of infinitive in detail : http://www.edufind.com/english/grammar/infinitive_function.php